# column value not exceeding 255 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, increment, auto-increment

I'm facing a slight problem. I have a primary key ID in a table set on autoincrement which is not allowing any value over 255 to be set. How should I go about fixing this? The higher the value which can be set, the better it is for me :)

Comment: Change type of primary key from byte to int

Comment: Why 255, you are using an integer value as a primary key with auto increment. If int is not enough you can use bigint.

Comment: Show the table definition.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use `TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED`, the maximum value in this case is 255.
Try to change the type of ID column, e.g. -

```
ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```